# How to create a tag for my maven-based project in Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I am trying to cut a release for my `Java` and `Maven` based `helloworld-api` project through `Jenkins` after doing the build and running the tests.

All I am having in my git repo (which is on Bitbucket) is the "master" branch.

I already have the Jenkins job integrated with `Bitbucket` successfully and it is pulling the changes from `Bitbucket` server and doing the build. But at the end of build I would also like to create a tag which I am not sure how to do.

I am not sure what I need to specify in the mandatory field that is shown in red.

I already have the git repo as:

```
https://jdoe@bitbucket.org/jdoe/helloworld-api.git
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git, remote name is the alias name that you have configured for your remote repository. By default, git uses *origin* as remote name for single remote counterpart.

So target remote name could be "**origin**" considering you have only one remote configured to your git repo